# Impossible to access to IIS site from internet

Tags: windows, iis, nat, ovh

I bought a domain name from OVH and I want to host my website locally. I made the following configurations:

Redirection of the domain name to my local ip address.
Modification of the OVH DNS IP on my NAT (FREEBOX REVOLUTION)
Port forwarding 80 - 443 - 5000 and 5001 on the NAT.
Opening via the firewall of the ports mentioned in point 3.
When I ping (via command prompt) my domainname.com on local server, I lose 0% and it returns my fixed IP from the NAT. When I ping my domainname.com via a smartphone (ping application on iPhone) I lose 100%. Obviously, it is impossible to access the website hosted from the outside. The site is managed through IIS on Windows.

In IIS I configured my application pool in the site settings (modification of permissions - security - add a new user - authorization of the application pool 'IIS AppPool \ monpool') so that it grants access to the site .

The problem is that despite these configurations, nothing allows me to access the site from the internet.

Comment: What is "my local ip address"? Compare it to what you get from https://www.whatismyip.com/ please. You might follow the right order to test out your web server, like I blogged in https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: Thank you for the link. Problem solve.

Comment: Post what you learned as an answer and accept it.